# How to run PSPP syntax file from the command line (CMD)?

Tags: windows, cmd, spss, pspp

I have the following syntax written in PSPP .sps file:

```
GET FILE =  '... result.sav'
save translate
        /outfile = '... data.csv'
        /type = CSV
        /REPLACE
        /FIELDNAMES
        /CELLS=LABELS.
```

where `...` stand for the path of the files.

The Script works as expected, so when I open PSPP and run it, it opens the first file and saves it as another CSV file. However, I would like to do two more things:

1. Call this file from CMD (in Windows) so it will execute all command automatically and silently, without showing the PSPP windows.
2. Add a line to the syntax to terminate PSPP after execution.

Right now I can only type the name of the .sps file in the CMD and it opens it but does nothing else. I have looked in [the official docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/pspp.html) but couldn't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself:

In CMD I had to type:

```
"C:\Program Files\PSPP\bin\pspp.exe" C:\Users\...\Dropbox\MATLAB\atid\convert_to_csv.sps
```

And that's all. It runs PSPP in silent mode and creates the file as needed.

What I didn't know was that I need to first write the path of PSPP .exe file (`"C:\Program Files\PSPP\bin\pspp.exe"`) before the name of the syntax file. All the rest just worked.